# Is $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int^{b - \delta}_b f(x) dx$ always zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Intuitively it seems obvious that $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int^{b - \delta}_b f(x) \ dx$ should always be zero. But is this definitely the case for all possible $ f(x) $?

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$, $b=0$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $b$, this holds rather trivially. If the integrals are improper, then it depends. If they converge, then it still holds (for example for $f(x)=1/\sqrt{|x|}, b=0$). If they diverge, the question is kinda meaningless, I think. In that case you are looking at a limit of a function that does not exist.

Comment: It is also true if $f$ is integrable in the sense of Lebesgue.

Comment: First, I assume you meant to write $b+\delta$. You're missing hypotheses. Are we assuming that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[b,b+\epsilon]$ Are we assuming the improper integral exists?

Comment: @SineoftheTime this is not even integrable

Comment: @pie in fact it's a counterexample